# How can I display Grand Total as a separate bar in stacked chart in SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, stacked-chart

How can I display `Grand Total` as a separate bar in stacked chart?
I broken down by Category Group which are `New Business` and `Renewal`. So how can I have another top bar that would show me a sum of `$` for `New Business` and `Renewal`?
Something like that:

[image]

EDIT:

Below is my main SELECT statement. I have created 
In first `UNION ALL` I created 'EQGrandTotal' as another `BusinessType`, then I summed up all types of premiums broken down by Description.

```
   SELECT   SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Bound'         THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as EQBoundNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Lost'          THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQLostNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up'  THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQNtUpNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Quoted'        THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQQuotedNB,
                    /* Earthquake, Renewal, by Description */
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Bound'          THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as EQBoundRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Lost'           THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQLostRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up'   THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQNtUpRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Quoted'         THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQQuotedRN,

                /* Wind, New Business, by Description */
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Bound'           THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as WindBoundNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Lost'            THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindLostNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up'    THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindNtUpNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Quoted'          THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindQuotedNB,
                /* Wind, Renewal, by Description */
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Bound'        THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as WindBoundRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Lost'         THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindLostRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up' THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindNtUpRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Quoted'       THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindQuotedRN,
        CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' THEN  'Earthquake' ELSE 'Wind' END as LineOfCoverage,
        'Earthquake' as Earthquake,
        'Wind' as Wind,
        BusinessType,
        Description,
        NULL as Total
FROM    cte_Quotes
GROUP BY LineOfCoverage,BusinessType,Description
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
        NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
        CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' THEN  'Earthquake' ELSE 'Wind' END as LineOfCoverage,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        'EQGrandTotal' as BusinessType,
        --NULL,
        Description, -- description
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Bound'         THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END)+
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Lost'          THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up'  THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END)+
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Quoted'        THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) +
                    /* Earthquake, Renewal, by Description */
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Bound'          THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END)+
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Lost'           THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up'   THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END)+
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Quoted'         THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as Total   
FROM    cte_Quotes
GROUP BY Description,LineOfCoverage,BusinessType
```

So I got another "BusinessType" group but the line is solid color. 
My expression for column `Total`:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!BusinessType.Value = "EQGrandTotal" and Fields!LineOfCoverage.Value = "Earthquake", Fields!Total.Value,0))
```

[image]

EDIT 2:
@Richards
Removed `UNION ALL` and instead Added 4 new columns:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Bound'         THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as EQBoundNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Lost'          THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQLostNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up'  THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQNtUpNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Quoted'        THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQQuotedNB,
                    /* Earthquake, Renewal, by Description */
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Bound'          THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as EQBoundRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Lost'           THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQLostRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up'   THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQNtUpRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Quoted'         THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQQuotedRN,

                /* Wind, New Business, by Description */
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Bound'           THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as WindBoundNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Lost'            THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindLostNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up'    THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindNtUpNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Quoted'          THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindQuotedNB,
                /* Wind, Renewal, by Description */
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Bound'        THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as WindBoundRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Lost'         THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindLostRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up' THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindNtUpRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Quoted'       THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindQuotedRN,
        CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' THEN  'Earthquake' ELSE 'Wind' END as LineOfCoverage,
        'Earthquake' as Earthquake,
        'Wind' as Wind,
        BusinessType,
        Description,

/*  Test @Richards*/

        SUM(CASE WHEN  Description = 'Bound'        THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as TotalBound,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = 'Lost'          THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as TotalLost,
        SUM(CASE WHEN  Description = 'Not Taken Up' THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as TotalNTU,
        SUM(CASE WHEN  Description = 'Quoted'       THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as TotalQuoted
FROM    cte_Quotes
GROUP BY LineOfCoverage,BusinessType,Description
```

The result in SSRS: 
I added `SUM(TotalBound)` as a value in a chart data and seems like the totals are gonna go on a top of the bars.

[image]

**EDIT 3:**
Added `UNION ALL` statement with `Totals` for each `Description`

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Bound'         THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as EQBoundNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Lost'          THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQLostNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up'  THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQNtUpNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Quoted'        THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQQuotedNB,
                    /* Earthquake, Renewal, by Description */
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Bound'          THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as EQBoundRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Lost'           THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQLostRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up'   THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQNtUpRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Quoted'         THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as EQQuotedRN,

                /* Wind, New Business, by Description */
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Bound'           THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as WindBoundNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Lost'            THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindLostNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up'    THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindNtUpNB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'New Business' AND Description = 'Quoted'          THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindQuotedNB,
                /* Wind, Renewal, by Description */
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Bound'        THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as WindBoundRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Lost'         THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindLostRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Not Taken Up' THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindNtUpRN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Wind' AND BusinessType = 'Renewal' AND Description = 'Quoted'       THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as WindQuotedRN,
        CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' THEN  'Earthquake' ELSE 'Wind' END as LineOfCoverage,
        'Earthquake' as Earthquake,
        'Wind' as Wind,
        BusinessType,
        Description,
        NULL as TotalBound,
        NULL as TotalLost,
        NULL as TotalNTU,
        NULL as TotalQuoted

FROM    cte_Quotes
GROUP BY LineOfCoverage,BusinessType,Description
UNION ALL 
SELECT  NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
        LineOfCoverage,--CASE WHEN LineOfCoverage = 'Earthquake' THEN  'Earthquake' ELSE 'Wind' END as LineOfCoverage,
        'Earthquake' as Earthquake,
        'Wind' as Wind,
        'Grand Total' as BusinessType,
        --NULL,
        Description, -- description
        SUM(CASE WHEN  Description = 'Bound'        THEN [Bound Premium] ELSE 0 END) as TotalBound,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = 'Lost'          THEN [LostPremium] ELSE 0 END) as TotalLost,
        SUM(CASE WHEN  Description = 'Not Taken Up' THEN [NotTakenUpPremium] ELSE 0 END) as TotalNTU,
        SUM(CASE WHEN  Description = 'Quoted'       THEN [QuotedPremium] ELSE 0 END) as TotalQuoted
FROM    cte_Quotes
GROUP BY Description,LineOfCoverage,BusinessType
```

Result in SSRS:

[image]

Comment: Hey Oleg! Can you add the SQL for the dataset you are using on this? You may have to union in some rows that roll up the Renew and New Business data. I would like to see the SQL to see if that is a viable option.

Comment: @Richards. I edited. Sorry if its little messy

Comment: oh, sorry. That was just one of my tests. I edited

Comment: Now that I see this, I am thinking a `UNION` may not be needed. Have you thought about adding some new columns (4) on the end of this `SELECT` that rolls up the totals? One each for Bound, Lost, NTU, and Quoted. Each a `SUM`, much like what you have for the others, but without LineOfCoverage and BusinessType in the mix. Does that make sense? I have something written up, but it's too much for a comment, and not quite an answer. I would have to mock some data to prove it out; I will do that if you think this might work.

Comment: @Richards I have edited query. Gonna try in SSRS

Comment: I edited. The idea is good, but seems like I need another `Description` column for each `LineOfCoverage`

Comment: That doesn't look right to me. Am I missing something? Or, will you be able to figure this out now?

Comment: the idea is to have totals as separate bar in a chart, not on the top of each bar. 
it represented on the top most picture where I posted the question

Comment: Okay. Well, I will have to think about this one some more. I may not have an answer until tomorrow, but I will see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks. I will also gonna be experimenting some more ideas.

Comment: @Richards   Thanks to you I think I got it right. I used your idea, I just added that statement in `UNION ALL` and created another `Business Type`.  Please, post the answer and I'll accept it.
Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my original comment, adding a `UNION` to the SQL that rolls up the summary data to the proper level made this possible.

This is useful technique in report writing when the tool won't do the rolling up for you.

Here is a simple example (from a database I have handy):

```
SELECT T.account_type_desc AS category, COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM account A JOIN account_type T
ON A.account_type_key = T.account_type_key
GROUP BY T.account_type_desc

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Grand Total' AS category, COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM account A
```

Glad I could help!!